# HttpClient не отправляет куки из CookieContainer, даже если secure=false

Tags: c#, .net-core

Пытаюсь авторизоваться через веб-версию ВКонтакте. Для этого я гружу страницу авторизации и отправляю POST-запрос, в котором должен быть логин-пароль, некоторые хеши, а также куки. Если с параметрами проблем нет, то куки не хотят отправляться.

```
static HttpResponseMessage sendRequest(HttpClient client, Uri url)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        response = responseTask.Result;
    }).Wait();
  return response;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://vk.com");
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(handler));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd(accept);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(uagent);
    var hresponse = sendRequest(httpClient, baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", hresponse.Headers);
    
    var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie count: {0}", cookies.Count);
                
    string content = "";
    hresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(_content =>
    {
        content = _content.Result;
    }).Wait();
    cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://login.vk.com/?act=login"));
    
    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
    {
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain)); // Пересоздать куки для Secure = false
    }
                
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie count: {0}", cookies.Count); // Выводит нормальное число куки
    
    httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.vk.com/?act=login", new FormUrlEncodedContent(postcontent.ToArray())).ContinueWith(_content =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test: {0}", _content.Result);
        hresponse = _content.Result;
    }).Wait();
}
```

Upd. Нашёл полу-решение добавить заголовок Cookie со всеми куками.

```
string cookieheader = "";
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
{
    cookieheader += String.Format("{0}={1}; ", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
}
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookieheader);
```

upd2.
Посмотрел трафик через BurpSuite, оказалось, что куки отправляются, а логгер этого не пишет.

Comment: Гляньте в браузере эти самые "куки" и посмотрите, есть ли там хоть какое либо упоминание `https://login.vk.com/?act=login`? Скажу сразу - нету, ибо Cookie привязываются к домену, это либо `vk.com`, либо `.vk.com` (все поддомены), либо вовсе на поддомен `login.vk.com` или `.login.vk.com`, но не используемый вами `https://login.vk.com/?act=login`.

Comment: Не брезгуйте [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62681494/12888024), код будет смотреться намного приятнее.

Comment: Еще заметил: `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")` вы уверены, что API vk.com вам отвечает в этой кодировке? Предполагаю, что можно использовать `Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, и не мучаться с кодировками, `HttpClient` перекодирует ответ в строку автоматически с указанием той кодировки, в которой получен ответ.

Comment: @aepot может и можно это убрать, просто через `ReadAsStringAsync()` на лине крашило, добавил `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)` и вроде крашить перестало, проверю.

@EvgeniyZ .vk.com, куки все выводятся, даже при указании просто vk,com в запросе они отсутствуют

Comment: @Stunner лучше переделайте на `async/await`, я вам выше скинул ссылку, оно не будет блочить вызывающий поток, пока грузит данные.

Comment: @aepot а смысл? Только для красоты кода? у меня пока это весь код

Comment: `.vk.com` и `vk.com` - это два совершенно разных домена. Ищите методы в интернете, которые рекурсивно возьмут все нужные куки из словаря и уже от туда берите нужную. Кстати странно, что вы вообще их пытаетесь взять. У вас есть словарь, в него система добавила уже все нужное, делайте запросы с этим словарем и все. А по поводу `async/await` - потом не жалуйтесь, что у вас приложение медленно работает, зависает окно и так далее.

Comment: Там еще куча `IDisposable` классов, которые вы не диспозите. Этот код по сути надежен только при первом и единственном запуске для тестов.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ с куками всё нормально. Если бы с ними было что-то не так, то у вк бы не работала авторизация. Что значит "делайте запросы с этим словарём"? Вы про CookieContainer? Он у меня к HttpClient привязан, по коду видно.

Comment: Привязан, да, только потом вы начинаете делать полную белиберду. Вот здесь `var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress);` вы получаете только то, что относиться к `vk.com`, не к `login.vk.com` и не к `.vk.com` (с точкой, которая говорит "все поддомены"). Далее вы делаете `.GetCookies(new Uri("https://login.vk.com/?act=login"));`, который вернет вам пустышку, ибо нету такого базового домена, как `https://login.vk.com/?act=login`, есть `login.vk.com`, есть `.vk.com` и скорей всего есть `.login.vk.com`, а их вы благополучно теряете и в следующее запросы кидаете не пойми что.

Comment: Так ведь это я просто для вывода делаю... При этом он выводит правильное количество ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А, ну раз это `handler.CookieContainer.Add` только для вывода, ну тогда я не знаю что тут не так, да...

Comment: Да даже без этого. Всё равно ничего ведь не работает. У меня проблема с отправкой куки, а в контейнере они есть. Эта часть кода для того чтобы все куки стали secure=false

Comment: `secure=false` это не выход, даже если бы оно на что-то здесь влияло. Вам была дана куча дельных рекомендаций по доменам, которые надо вязать к кукам. Не сработало? По кодировке там, код наверное уже отличается от того, что в вопросе. Быть может, стоит обновить?